# What is the best technique to deal with missing information in test data?

Tags: time-series, data-science, forecasting

Let's assume I have 5 features;

**feature 1, feature 2, feature 3, year, country and outcome** that I trined a mode on them.
And now I want to predict the outcome in the new year (the new year does not include in the training dataset) and specific country but I do not have information for other features.

so how can I create assumptions for this missing data or there are any statistical techniques that can help to fill this missing whether numerical or category. ( I am not sure if I apply the mean or mode to fill these data it will help me to make a good prediction )